# Credentials are Either Invalid or Unspecified

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am using bing Maps in my app. When i am using the Get Directions it's showing this error. How to solve it. I googled for hours but hasn't got any help. Pleas help.

These are the two services which i am hitting.

http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc/mex
http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc/mex

Or Please give me Step by Step Procedure to work with the bing maps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Bing Map Sample application given in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) .It has code which shows how to implement Bing Map.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is often due to missing or incorrect credentials. You need to have an API key to access the Bing Maps services. This [blog post](http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2010/03/21/Using-the-Silverlight-Bing-Maps-control-on-the-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) includes a description of how to get a key and set it in your project.